# strlen() is returning a value that includes the null terminator

Tags: c, string, clang

I'm using a Ubuntu Machine compiling with Clang.

I'm reading a simple file, storing it into a buffer then getting the length. I'm anticipating receiving a 5 but got a 6.

`strlen()` isn't suppose to include the null terminator. Is this perhaps because I performed a cast on the buffer?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    unsigned char buffer[30];
    memset(buffer, '\0', 30);

    int fd_read = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    read(fd_read, buffer, 29);

    ssize_t length = strlen((const char *)buffer);
    printf("%zu\n", length);
}
```

Contents of **test.txt**:

```
Hello
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: Print out the hex values of each of the 6 bytes. What value does `read` return?

Comment: Does your file perhaps end in a line feed? What does `od -t c test.txt` show? (I'm assuming the fact that read `test.txt` but showed the contents of `Test.txt` is a typo and adjusted your question accordingly.)

Comment: Probably have a newline in the file after the visible string.

Comment: Tip: `buffer[fd_read] = 0;` makes more sense than `memset(buffer, '\0', 30);`

Comment: You're right, `od -t c test.txt` includes a newline character. The Ubuntu default text editor didn't indicate this; other editors did.

Comment: When in doubt do a hex dump of the file, to see exactly what it contains. Aside: MS Visual C can write stuff to the supposedly 'unused' part of the buffer, even when the file size was smaller, and I don't know if that part of the buffer is supposed to be protected in any way by a C standard (you indicated to `read` it was available). Just use the value returned by the function and nul terminate the buffer afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

> *strlen() isn't suppose to include the null terminator.*

That is true.

> *Is this perhaps because I performed a cast on the buffer?*

The cast is unnecessary but it is not what is causing the problem.

> *I'm reading a simple file, storing it into a buffer then getting the length. I'm anticipating receiving a 5 but got a 6.*

The likely scenario is that you have newline character at the end of the read string, as pointed out by Chris Dodd, which `strlen` will count. To remove it:

```
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

Other considerations about your code:

- You should verify the return value of `open` to confirm that the file was successfuly accessed.
- `memset(buffer, '\0', 30);` is unnecessary, you can null terminate `buffer`:

  ```
  ssize_t nbytes = read(fd_read, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);

  if(nbytes >= 0)  
      buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
  ```

  Or you can initialize the array with 0s:

  ```
  unsigned char buffer[30] = {'\0'}; // or 0
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Your program is somewhat convoluted, using modified types for no reason. Yet the problem does not come from these typing issues nor the use of casts, it is much more likely the file contains 6 bytes instead 5, namely the letters `Hello` and a newline<sup>(*)</sup>.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[30] = { 0 };

    int fd_read = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_read >= 0) {
        int count = read(fd_read, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
        size_t length = strlen(buffer);
        printf("count=%d, length=%zu\n", count, length);
        printf("contents: {");
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("%3.2X", (unsigned char)buffer[i]);
        }
        printf(" }\n");
        close(fd_read);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(*)or possibly on legacy platforms, `Hello` and an end of line sequence CR/LF (7 bytes) that is translated to a single `'\n'` byte by the `read` library function that is a wrapper on system calls that performs complex postprocessing</sup>